# Is there a .NETCF 3.5 SP1? or is it still at just 3.5?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, compact-framework, redistributable

Does the .NET Compact Framework have a service pack?  If so does anyone know where the redist download is?

I found this: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E3821449-3C6B-42F1-9FD9-0041345B3385&displaylang=en

But it is just for 3.5.  I think that is current, but I don't want to get burned by setting up older stuff for my devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa497273.aspx) page, the link you found is the most current.